# PHP `DateTime::days` returns trash?

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3

PHP Class `DateInterval` has a property "days". According to the manual it returns
"Total number of days the interval spans. If this is unknown, days will be FALSE."

In my case the code:

```
$d = new DateInterval('P1Y'); 
echo $d->days;
```

returns `-99999`

and a code like this

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", "01.01.2010");
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", "03.01.2010");

$d = $b->diff($a);
echo $d->days;
```

returns `6015`

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DateInterval is buggy on windows platform. See [bug #51183](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184). The official answer seems to be "use VC9 builds instead for now".

Comment: The bug was reported an year ago and they tagged it as "wont fix" because "It is not something we can easily fix". Are they sick!?

Answer (score 2):

I just run your examples and they should work. Specifically I got:

```
    $d = new DateInterval('P1Y');
    var_dump($d->days);
    // result: int 0


    $a = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", "01.01.2010");
    $b = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", "03.01.2010");

    $d = $b->diff($a);
    var_dump($d->days);
    // result: int 2
```

I'm running XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a with PHP 5.3.1 on Linux Mint 10.

Answer (score 0):

Can u please tell me your exact solution you need...

I have used the code below,

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');
```

echo $interval->d;

it gives the **o/p as 4**

if i use like this,

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y');

echo $interval->d;
```

it gives **o/p as 0**

So it will return the day u have given in Dateinterval() otherwise it will return zero..

U tell me ur exact requirement please.......... :)

Comment: I am speaking not about "->d", but about "->days". According to manual it must be a total number of days, but it is not... at least not in Windows.