# PHP: Unexpected total amount of days from date diff

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP `DateTime::days` returns trash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933441/php-datetimedays-returns-trash)

Ok, I don't get this... Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');

$a = new DateTime('2011-06-20 21:00:00');
$b = new DateTime('2011-06-21 05:30:00');

echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo $b->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

echo $a->diff($b)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
echo $a->diff($b)->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds').PHP_EOL;
```

The output I get is:

```
2011-06-20 21:00:00
2011-06-21 05:30:00
6015 days, 8 hours, 30 minutes and 0 seconds
0 years, 0 months, 0 days, 8 hours, 30 minutes and 0 seconds
```

What is up with the days here? Shouldn't it be 0 in both cases?

Comment: It's a known bug on Windows. Hang on, looking for a dupe

Comment: Ah! That explains why it works @ my server. :)

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, that explained it! Although seriously... what developers lets a bug like this lay unfixed for this long? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should, and it does on my system:

```
nanne@pustule:~$ cat test.php
<?
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');

$a = new DateTime('2011-06-20 21:00:00');
$b = new DateTime('2011-06-21 05:30:00');

echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo $b->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

echo $a->diff($b)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
```

//

```
nanne@pustule:~$ php test.php
2011-06-20 21:00:00
2011-06-21 05:30:00
0 days, 8 hours, 30 minutes and 0 seconds
```

As @pekka commented: it seems to be a bug in PHP for windows systems :D

Comment: Yep! Crazy annoying... I mean, come on PHP people, that's a bug that should be fixed long ago!